# Delphi CEF Check if site is not reachable

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded, tchromium

I'm use CEF 3.2623.1401.gb90a3be (Chromium 49.0.2623.110) in my project in Delphi 10.1. (I have to use a fairly old version of CEF/Chromium for backwards compatibility with WinXP). How do I can check if a site is not reachable? if I try to open any obviously non-existent or inaccessible site in a normal Chrome browser - I get an error like `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` or `ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`, but in my embedded Chromium I get just a blank page without anything. Can I somehow catch such errors in Chromium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. There is the [**OnLoadError**](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefLoadHandler.html#OnLoadError(CefRefPtr%3CCefBrowser%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefFrame%3E,ErrorCode,constCefString&,constCefString&)) event that you can handle (error codes you can then find in the **ceferr.pas** module).